# How to scrape tags inside li tag using python selinum

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I use selinum to scrape data from this website: https://www.sciencedirect.com/search?qs=physics.
I want to select a specific tag inside

tag.
This is the structure of HTML.
[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFcp5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not post code as an image. Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Since I don't have the complete source code, I can only guess. You have to use an appropriate find strategy like `CSS_SELECTOR` or `XPATH`. Check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=CSS_SELECTOR#locating-elements).

Here is an example by using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
element = driver.find_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.result-list-title-link > span.anchor-text > span"
).text
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying, I have tested this code to get only specific element in li tag.                                                                                                  
 outhor_name = html_list.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="srp-results-list"]/ol/li[2]'

Comment: for i in outhor_name:
    print(i.text)

Comment: The problem is I get only one author name, I don't know how to change "srp-results-list"]/ol/li[2]" to iterate al author name element in <li>. If you have any idea about this, thank's for helping me.

Comment: Use `find_elements` to select multiple elements rather than a single one with `find_element`.